# Conceptual doubts regarding Rest and Soap : Backends for Frontend

Tags: rest, soap

I have 2 years in the IT industry,i love to read a lot ,but when i go deep in some subjects i see a lot of contradiction in somes articles,forum or terms that are used interchangeable.

I understand the difference between Soap and Rest.
When we want to communicate between backends, we can use either of these 2 approaches, each with its advantages and disadvantages.

**Situation :**

If i have an application, which can be monolithic or not, where I have a backend and I will only have a front end that consumes it. Usually we create a Rest Api so that our front end can consume it. But we will never think about exposing our backend with Soap.(Lot of reasons)

**Questions:**

1 -Is it okay if I say that Rest , in addition to allowing us to exchange information between application and application (backend to backend ), is it also useful when exposing services for our front end? And SOAP is only useful for Server - Server communication?

2 -And finally, if I expose a backend only for a front end, it is ok to say that we expose a web service or conceptually we say that it is a backend for frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: No the First question is wrong Assumption. We can say that in SOAP, XML is the only means of communication, while in Rest, the accepted means is JSON, while there are other formats like XML, JSON, PDF, HTML etc. and Ofcourse, XML can be converted back  from server into UI Language and XML Request deciphered at Server for a Response. So, its not Ok to say that SOAP is only for Server - Server Communication.
2. No, when you have  typically exposed backend only for consumption by a Front end, you can typically say that it is a backend for numerous front end client requests. But IMO, Backend for a front end is a monolithic webapplication, both bundled in WAR. so in that sense, any UI Request can request response from the Back end web service. Hope i am able to clear your understanding about web services.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! So ,you are saying that if i have a BFF i cant call that a Web Service?

Comment: Webservice is back end service hosted on server. any client which is exchanging data with server according to the format(XML or JSON) can exchange data with webservice. for eg.., current time is webservice and various clients across globe access current world time webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your question there are actually 4 embedded independent topics. And probably because they are always used in conjunction it is sometimes tough to understand.

I will give a short answer first:

- REST and SOAP both can be used for Client-Server and Server-Server integrations. But the choice will be dependent on the questions like where you want server-side UI technology/client-side UI technology **or** is it a single page application/portal technology, etc.
- If you expose a single-backend for a single-frontend it's technically a BFF although the term BFF is used only in the case where you have separate-backends for each type of frontend application. e.g. one for mobile, one for web, one for IoT devices, etc.

The long answer is to clarify the 4 principles. Let me give a try at this by separating the topics into the below four headings:

### 1. Backend(Business Layer) vs Backend for frontend(BFF)

- In classical 3-tier architecture (UI-Business Layer-Database) world, the middle-layer that consists of the business and integration logic is mostly referred to as backend/business layer.
- This layer can be separated from the UI/Frontend using multiple different options like APIs(REST/SOAP), RPC, Servlet Technology, etc. The limitation with this 3-tier architecture is that, it is still tightly coupled to the type of users and use-cases are limited to web/browser based. It is not a good choice when you want to reuse the business-layer for both web and mobile as the mobile applications are required to be light-weight by principle.
- That's where we lean on to multi-tier architecture with Backend For Frontend(BFF) as a savior. It's just a methodology to segregate the business-layers based on consumers.

### 2. Monolith vs SOA vs Microservices(Optimized SOA)

- In a monolith world all the code components mostly UI and Business Layer sits in a tightly coupled fashion. The simplest example would be a Java Servlet Pages(JSP) application with Java as Business Layer. These are typically server-side UI technologies.
- In Service Oriented Architecture(SOA), the usecases revolve around leveraging reusable business layer functions aka services. Here one would have to deal with UI-Server, Inter-Service and Server-Server integration scenarios. It's heavily service dependent, meaning it's like a spider-web of dependent applications.
- The Microservices is an extension of SOA, but the approach is to keep a resource in focus instead of services to reduce the spider-web dependencies. Hence, self-sufficient and standalone service-clusters are the base of micro-services architecture.

### 3. SOAP vs REST Webservices

- SOAP stands for Simple Object Access Protocol, typically used by the business-layer ***to provide user-defined methods/services to manipulate an object***. For example look at the names of the services for accessing a book collection

1. To get a book getABook()
2. Get the whole list of books listAllBooks()
3. Find a book by name searchABook(String name)
4. Update a book's details updateABookDetails()

- On the other hand, REST is representational state transfer which ***transfers the state of a web-resource to the client using underlying existing HTTP methods***. So the above services for accessing a book collection would look like

1. To get a book /book(HTTP GET)
2. Get the whole list of books /books(HTTP GET)
3. Find a book by name /book?name={search}(HTTP GET)
4. Update a book's details /book/{bookId}(HTTP PATCH/PUT)

### 4. How to make a correct choice of architecture?

- Spot the diversity of the application user groups and usages: This will help to understand the platform(web/mobile/IoT/etc), nature of the application and session-management.
- Determine the estimated/required throughput: This will help you to understand the scalability requirements.
- How frequently and who will be maintaining the application: This will help to gauge the application and technology complexity, deployment cycles, deployment strategy, appetite for downtime, etc.

***In conclusion, always follow the divine rule of KISS: Keep it simple, stupid.***

Comment: Hey ! Thank you very much for your explanation and for your time! So is ok to say that a simple Business Layer or a BFF beeing consumed why just one front end is a kind of Web Service too? Because some people say a Web Service is more related to expose something to be consumed by different types of clients in some kind of Enterprise way. Even in my example ,we still have an interface to communicate and to interact with the backend/services,the only difference is that only provides data to a Front end.

Comment: Yes definitely it would be fine to call it a web-service as your front-end would be using this over some sort of network(in this case HTTP). 

Refer: https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebServices

Answer (score 0):

1.)

A webapplication is for H2M communication a webservice is for M2M communication through the web. The interface of the service is more standardized, more structured, so machines can easily use it and parse the messages.

I don't think it matters where your service consumer is, it can run in a browser or it can run on the server. As long as it can communicate with the service on a relative safe channel it is ok.

You design a service usually to decouple it from multiple different consumers, so you don't have to deal with the consumer implementations. This makes sense usually when you have potentially unknown consumers programmed usually by 3rd party programmers you don't even know or want to know about. You version the service or at least the messages to stay compatible with old consumers.

If you have only a single consumer developed by you, then it might be too much extra effort to maintain a service with a quasi-standard interface. You can easily change the code of the consumer when you change the interface of the service, so thinking about interface design, standardization, backward compatibility, etc. does not make much sense. Though you can still use REST or SOAP ad hoc without much design. In this case having a RESTish CRUD API without hypermedia is a better choice I think.

2.)

I think both are good, I would say backend in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! Sometimes ,some concepts have different views .I really liked your answer! Thanks again!